# Poor sound quality with elementary OS on an iMac 2011

Tags: audio, imac, elementaryos

I've got elementary OS 5.1.7 installed on my iMac 27" 2011 in order to give it a second life. Besides some minor struggles (I'm a noob when it comes to linux), there is one final problem: audio / sound quality. The default is awful, without bass and very tinny. So I figured out there is "alsamixer" where to set the sound quality. There I managed to achieve much better results. The problem is when I push the volume button on the keyboard (regardless of wired or bluetooth Apple Keyboard) the setting are set back to the awful default. There is no "save settings" control within "alsamixer". I figured out, that I can store the configuration manually and let it start with booting the machine - but again, pushing the volume key on the keyboard sets everything back. Also with doing the setting as superuser, pushing one of the volume keys sets back als setting in alsamixer. Pulseaudio package is installed, too. Is there a possibility to keep the setting and use the volume keys on the keyboard?